# regex replace multiple patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new in programming and need some help ;-)
how can I replace *multiple patterns* in a `string`?

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string input = "this is a test AAA one more test adakljd jaklsdj BBB sakldjasdkj CCC";
  string [] pattern = {"AAA", "BBB","CCC"};
  string replacement = "XXX";

  string result = null;
  for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
  {
    result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern[i], replacement);
  }

  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Want the result:

> this is a test **XXX** one more test adakljd jaklsdj **XXX** sakldjasdkj **XXX**

But I get:

> this is a test **AAA** one more test adakljd jaklsdj **BBB** sakldjasdkj **XXX**

thx for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex, you simply can use `Replace`:

```
string input = "this is a test AAA one more test adakljd jaklsdj BBB sakldjasdkj CCC";
string replaced = input.Replace("AAA", "XXX").Replace("BBB", "XXX")...
```

Comment: I'd imagine `AAA` etc are placeholders for what could be more intricate regex

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *combining* all patterns' parts (`"AAA", ..., "CCC"`) with **|** ("or"):

```
  string input = "this is a test AAA one more test adakljd jaklsdj BBB sakldjasdkj CCC";
  string[] pattern = { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
  string replacement = "XXX";

  string result = Regex.Replace(
    input, 
    string.Join("|", pattern.Select(item => $"(?:{item})")), 
    replacement);

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
this is a test XXX one more test adakljd jaklsdj XXX sakldjasdkj XXX
```

I've turned each pattern part like `BBB` into a *group* `(?:BBB)` in case pattern part contains `|` within itself

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the `result` variable throughout the loop repeatedly, there doesn't seem to be any need for it either, just use the `input` variable

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, pattern[i], replacement);
...
Console.WriteLine(input);
```